# How to split a multi-line string in string array in vb.net using Delimeter?

Tags: vb.net, split

I have utility in VB language. That splits the string. User provide string(may be multiline string) and delimiter. And output will be string array. What will be the input delimiter to split string from new Line?.

Currently I am using `Dim output = Split(InputString, delimiter)` to split string.

In VB code there is option `Environment.NewLine`.

But end user know only "\n" for new line.

So my question is What will be the input delimiter to split string from new Line?

Comment: You can specify more than one delimiter. For example, `dim result = inputString.Split({vbCrLf, vbLf, vbCr}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` will split the input string using `\r\n`, `\n` and `\r`, returning an array of strings.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for prompt response but What should I take user input for delimiter?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Do you have some other delimiter(s) inside the string and you need to split the string using this (these) delimiter(s) too? Add them to the list of delimiters, along with `vbCrLf` & Co.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `vbCrLf`, `vbLf` or `vbCr`, depending on what is in your string.

If they are typing the text in a TextBox or saving it in a file, `vbCrLf` should split your string into individual lines.

Comment: What should I take user input for delimiter?